# Display a variable-sized collection of TextBlocks/ComboBoxes in Silverlight 3

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I have a list of textual descriptions, each of which a user must score on a scale of 1-5.  The number of textual descriptions is variable, so I can't just define a static Grid in XAML.

The following image shows approximately what I'm after:

[image]

In ASP.NET, I could bind my list of text items to a Repeater control.  For each row, the text would be displayed in a Label, and next to it would be a DropDownList that contains a static list of items.  Is there a similar control available in Silverlight?

Should I be using one of these?

- DataGrid
- ListBox
- Custom control derived from ItemsControl
- (Other)

Comment: Just found a possible solution: http://wildermuth.com/2009/01/18/Fun_with_ItemsControl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using an ItemsControl, and within the ItemTemplate I placed the TextBlock and ComboBox controls.

The only wrinkle for me was that the ComboBox depended on a separate DataContext, so I had to resort to using the DataContextProxy described in [this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2009/08/20/creating-a-silverlight-datacontext-proxy-to-simplify-data-binding-in-nested-controls.aspx)